# Assembly x86 : Comparaison Between Variable And Register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I was trying to compare a variable to a register and to increment this variable, without success.

```
section .data
i : DB 0x0

global foo:function

foo:
cmp i, rdx
...
inc i
```

But Nasm is not pleased.
I found a solution, storing 0x0 in a register, cmp and inc on this register. But I'm curious, and can you manipulate variable ?

thx

Answer (score 4):

In NASM referring to variables is always done via the use of square brackets **[ ]**.

NASM doesn't store size information about a variable. This means `inc i` is not enough. Here you need to code `inc byte [i]`.

Since the variable **i** was defined as a byte you don't want to compare it with a qword register like RDX. You can code `cmp [i],dl`.